# How do I test an Api Controller [httpget] Method, using a console application

Tags: c#

I am trying to test a api controller methods using a console app. I am trying to test the GetCustomerInfo method, that searches the database with the id. I can not figure out how to test the parameter that goes into the method.
My Controller method

```
[Route("GETCustomerInfo/{Id}")]
[HttpGet("{Id}")]
public Persons GETCustomerInfo(int id)
{
    Persons customerInfo;
    ListFromRepository.TryGetValue(id, out customerInfo);
    return customerInfo;
}
```

My console application test method

```
public override async Task<bool> ExecuteTests()
{
    HttpResponseMessage res =  await  HttpClientConnection.GetAsync("Default/GetCustomerInfo/Id")
    res.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    if(res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Question: why not use a unit test?

Comment: Another question:  *"I can not figure out how to test the parameter that goes into the method"*; you mean something like: `https://www.yourdomain.here/Default/GetCustomerInfo/12345` or `https://www.yourdomain.here/Default/GetCustomerInfo?id=12345`?

Comment: I can not figure out how to test it in the console application i can use     HttpResponseMessage res = await HttpClientConnection.GetAsync("Default/GetCustomerInfo/1") and it works but i want to be able to insert an id in the test and have it do it automaticlly

Comment: I agree that the unit test would be a good way to go. From a console app, I don't see that the path you're using will work. The console app needs to have the API running, and the console then connects as localhost. So your GetAsync would be "http://localhost:[apirunningport]/Default/GetCustomerInfo/[somecustomerid]"

Comment: I am running it at the same time. the httpclientconnection has the baseaddress set to "localhost:domain/api/"

Comment: Would it be reasonable to just write a unit test that constructed the controller object and then called the method directly?  All that you are losing is testing the routing to your controller action in that case.  The actual functioning of the controller action can be fully tested.

Comment: `I can not figure out how to test it in the console application i can use HttpResponseMessage res = await HttpClientConnection.GetAsync("Default/GetCustomerInfo/1") and it works but i want to be able to insert an id in the test and have it do it automaticlly` <= I am not following. You do not understand how to append an `int` (id) to a `string` (url)??

Comment: when i use 
    HttpResponseMessage res = await HttpClientConnection.GetAsync("Default/GetCustomerInfo/{id}");
i get a 400 for http staus code. when i use
HttpResponseMessage res = await HttpClientConnection.GetAsync("Default/GetCustomerInfo/1"); it works, i want to able to work with any number id

Comment: *"`HttpClientConnection.GetAsync("Default/GetCustomerInfo/1");`  it works, i want to able to work with any number id"*, : What do you mean by *"any id"*? You want to pass the ìd` as command line argument? Or do you want to create a loop?

Comment: https://www.yourdomain.here/Default/GetCustomerInfo/12345
So when I put in any number  ex]12345
the number will be sent here
  
  HttpClientConnection.GetAsync("Default/GetCustomerInfo/12345